# sf lines to polygons with holes

Tags: r, polygonize, sf, holes

With `sp` package I generate automatically boundaries for different sets of spatial points. I'm trying to perform the same workflow with `sf` package but i had problems for detecting holes in the way `sp` does.
To this dataset i calculate a set of lines that make up the boundary and the inner ring, merge the lines and convert to polygon.
This is what i do with `sp`:

```
library(sp)
library(maptools)
library(rgeos)
# ln.lns is the list of 'Lines' (mentioned above) as defined by sp
splns1 <- SpatialLines(LinesList = ln.lns,
          proj4string = "+proj=utm +zone=20 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
splns2 <- gLineMerge(splns1)
sp3 <- SpatialLines2PolySet(splns2)
sp4 <- PolySet2SpatialPolygons(sp3)
sp5 <- createSPComment(sp4)
plot(sp4, col = "blue", axes = T)
plot(p1p, pch = 1, add = T)
```

This results in `sp5` being a SpatialPolygons as desired: a hole in the middle and not another polygon:

[image: polygon with points]
When i try to implement the equivalent procedure with `sf`, it creates a polygon in the middle and not a hole:

```
library(sf)
splns1 <- st_sfc(ln.lns, crs = "+proj=utm +zone=20 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
splns2 <- st_combine(splns1)
splns3 <- st_line_merge(splns2)
sp3 <- st_polygonize(splns3)
plot(sp3, col = "blue", axes = T)
plot(p1, add=T)
```

[image: sf polygons without hole]

What can I do to arrive at the same result in `sf` being that it should be able to run unsupervised?

### (Update 9/11/2017)

This two data frames have the start and end points for the lines in the boundary. Below I put how I compute the lines in each package:

```
lon <- data.frame(x1 = c(438867.9, 438907.3, 438900.2, 438893.1, 438886.1, 
438879.1, 438903.7, 438941.8, 438935.1, 438928.2, 438921.3,
438910.3, 438941.8, 438951.9, 438931.4, 438931.4, 438877.6, 438864.1, 
438864.1, 438877.6, 438936.0, 438915.7,
438882.2, 438869.1, 438869.1, 438909.0, 438922.4, 438953.2, 438952.5, 
438945.9, 438939.4, 438933.1, 438927.0,
438920.9, 438914.9, 438908.6, 438902.2, 438895.8, 438889.4, 438882.9, 
438876.4, 438858.0, 438865.0, 438907.3,
438942.5, 438882.2, 438936.0, 438858.0, 438951.9, 438954.4),
x2 = c(438869.8, 438900.2, 438893.1, 438886.1, 438879.1, 438872.0, 438897.2, 
438935.1, 438928.2, 438921.3, 438914.4,
438903.7, 438942.5, 438945.3, 438910.3, 438931.8, 438897.2, 438860.7, 
438865.0, 438878.9, 438931.8, 438909.0,
438878.9, 438865.0, 438867.9, 438902.6, 438915.7, 438954.4, 438945.9, 
438939.4, 438933.1, 438927.0, 438920.9,
438914.9, 438908.6, 438902.2, 438895.8, 438889.4, 438882.9, 438876.4, 
438869.8, 438860.7, 438872.0, 438914.4,
438945.3, 438902.6, 438922.4, 438865.0, 438953.2, 438952.5))
lat <- data.frame(y1 = c(5991927, 5991829, 5991830, 5991831, 5991832, 
5991833, 5991848, 5991825, 5991826, 5991827, 5991828, 5991847, 5991825,
5991879, 5991864, 5991864, 5991871, 5991873, 5991873, 5991871, 5991898, 
5991921, 5991905, 5991906, 5991906, 5991922,
5991920, 5991895, 5991935, 5991936, 5991936, 5991937, 5991938, 5991939, 
5991940, 5991940, 5991941, 5991942, 5991943,
5991944, 5991944, 5991835, 5991834, 5991829, 5991843, 5991905, 5991898, 
5991835, 5991879, 5991916),
y2 = c(5991945, 5991830, 5991831, 5991832, 5991833, 5991834, 5991848, 
5991826, 5991827, 5991828, 5991829, 5991848, 5991843,
5991862, 5991847, 5991881, 5991848, 5991853, 5991890, 5991888, 5991881, 
5991922, 5991888, 5991890, 5991927, 5991923,
5991921, 5991916, 5991936, 5991936, 5991937, 5991938, 5991939, 5991940, 
5991940, 5991941, 5991942, 5991943, 5991944,
5991944, 5991945, 5991853, 5991834, 5991829, 5991862, 5991923, 5991920, 
5991834, 5991895, 5991935))
```

Creating the list of lines with `sp`:

```
ln.lns <- lapply(X = 1:nrow(lon),
             FUN = function(x) Lines(list(Line(cbind(c(lon[x, 1], lon[x, 2]),
                                                     c(lat[x, 1], lat[x, 2])))),
                                     ID = paste0("ln", x)))
```

Creating the list of lines with `sf`:

```
ln.lns <- lapply(X = 1:nrow(lon),
             FUN = function(x) st_linestring(cbind(c(lon[x, 1], lon[x, 2]),
                                                   c(lat[x, 1], lat[x, 2])),
                                             dim = "XY"))
```

Comment: can you show how you get your lines object from your points?

Comment: just for fun I tried a "finite element" approach to this here http://rpubs.com/cyclemumner/306128

Comment: @mdsumner fun (and sfdct is new to me!) but doesn't really help. We still need to know how the lines are constructed, since these define the polygon, and in the general case might not be the largest hole in the triangulation!

Comment: @Spacedman i edited the post with the coordinates of the lines segments

Comment: Anyway @mdsumner i liked your approach with finite element, seems much simpler and straightforward, do you think it should work in most cases?

Comment: not in general no, hence the fun caveat -  but having heuristics like this can help you understand why it's not possible in general to infer shape boundaries from unstructured points (see concaveman and alphahull for related heuristics, that probably won't work either)

Comment: @mdsumner actually the lines that i use for making the boundary are built with `alphahull::ashape` and with `sp` it's been working almost flawlessly. The problem came when trying to _translate_ everything to `sf` functions (when i say everything i mean from `ashape` onwards )

Comment: Ah I see. If you want to pose the question as how to work with sf and alphahull together I'd be happy to explore that. That is key information, and without it we were not seeing what you were really asking, I think. To me this is a good question, since the landscape of packages is so disparate and fragemented.  In terms of alphahull sp and sf aren't so different anyway and conversions/constructors are trivial to do (but hard to learn about).

Comment: @mdsumner i didn't think the post should be about `alphahull` and `sf` because `ashape` only needs a matrix of coordinates, whether they come from `sp::coordinates` or `sf::st_coordinates` it shouldn't mind right? My problem came when working with it's outcome and how to process it

Comment: Remove the raw points from the question then as they are not relevant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you have created a GEOMETRYCOLLECTION which can be an unstructured set of linear features, in other words there's no concept of holes and islands.

What you want is a MULTIPOLYGON. So first cast your lines to MULTIPOLYGON:

```
> stc = st_cast(splns2,"MULTIPOLYGON")
```

This doesn't work if your rings are in the wrong direction, so fix that up by making it valid:

```
> stv = st_make_valid(stc)
> plot(stv,col="blue")
```

[image: holey polygon Batman]

As per Edzer's comment on r-sig-geo, conversion to MULTIPOLYGON and a round-trip via `sp` objects seems to work in the absence of liblwgeom:

```
 plot(
   st_as_sf(
      as(
         st_cast(splns3,"MULTIPOLYGON"),
         "Spatial")
        ),col="blue")
```

Comment: I'll have to take your word on that as I'm using a the Windows binary version of the `sf` package and it says `st_make_valid requires compilation against liblwgeom`

Comment: I've been trying to workaround this but had no luck. Can you help in compiling `sf` in Windows linked to libwlgeom or should i make a separte post?

Comment: Might be an idea to raise it as an issue here: https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues

Comment: Some discussion here: https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/67